# How to correctly import a header and footer in Node.js without a template engine?

Tags: node.js

How can I correctly import a header and footer to HTML via Node.js without any template engine? I didn't find an answer on the internet. The only idea I have is reading the HTML file as text and replacing some tag (so creating something like my own template engine), but I don't know if this is the way to go.

Comment: Please add more information to the question, are you using frameworks? Simple file? Please show use something. Thanks

Comment: @CarloCorradini I am only using express.

Comment: Yes ok, but with express are you using some frameworks? Handlebars? Vue? React? Webpack? Something similar? Please add more information and some code so we can help you with your question. Thanks :)

Comment: @CarloCorradini this is the reason why I am saying only. I am only using express. without any frameworks.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't reference (and load) another html file into the "main" html one without any template engine. Take a look [HERE](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html). The guide exmplains how to use a template engine in express -> it's super useful / powerful and fairly simple. [Here](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/template-engines.html) is the list of compatible template engines. Hope it helps.